# PHP: resize all the images in a directory using imagick?

Tags: php

I have a folder with 100's of images in it. I need to resize all the images using `imagick`.

for a single image I can run:

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert images/image-name.jpg -resize 550x413  images/image-name.jpg");
```

But how would i go about doing the same thing with all the images?

is there any foreach loop function that I could use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't show you an example, so I won't post an answer. You can loop over files in a directory with readdir. The documentation with examples can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load all images in array then execute your method in `foreach` loop. To load all images in specific array you can use the following command:

```
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
foreach ($images_array as $item) {
    //your code goes here 
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand you. The `$item` variable holds image name.

Comment: so I can do exec("/usr/bin/convert images/".$item." -resize 550x413  images/".$item.""); ?